# Elasticsearch does not recognize yyyyMMddHHmmssS date

Tags: elasticsearch, date-format

I want to index documents to elasticsearch that have a date format that looks as follows: `201012301152521`
I believe I would just need to specify the elastic index pattern with the format as `yyyyMMddHHmmssS`, but somehow it doesn't recognize it. During the same indexing, I am also indexing other dates, where indexing works.

I am sitting on this for hours now already, but nothing works. I also already became very creative on the formats to no avail.

Note: I don't really care about the last character `S` and also not really about the seconds...but I also haven't found a way to ignore them in the format.

EDIT:

Colleague was so nice as to create a test case for this:

```
PUT testdate
{  "mappings": {
     "dynamic": false,
     "properties": {
       "col1": { "type": "date", 
                 "format": "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
       }
    }
  }
}

POST testdate/_doc/1
{
  "col1": "20170802123415"
}
# => SUCCESS


PUT testdate
{  "mappings": {
     "dynamic": false,
     "properties": {
       "col1": { "type": "date", 
                 "format": "yyyyMMddHHmmssS"
       }
    }
  }
}

POST testdate/_doc/1
{
  "col1": "201708021234150"
}
# => ERROR
```

We are using elasticsearch version 7.1.1

Edit2:
The error we are getting is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse field [col1] of type [date] in document with id '1'"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse field [col1] of type [date] in document with id '1'",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "failed to parse date field [201708021234150] with format [yyyyMMddHHmmssS]",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "date_time_parse_exception",
        "reason": "Text '201708021234150' could not be parsed at index 0"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: please share the mappings request and elasticsearch version

Comment: What error do you get when indexing documents?

Comment: Adjusted the question to include more information.